# What does ' ' do in Console.Write();

Tags: c#

I'm trying to  write all the elements of an array and this works ofcourse:

```
foreach (int i in arr)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```

but this:

```
foreach (int i in arr)
{
    Console.Write(i + ' ');
}
```

returns something completely different. Why is that?

Edit:
Let's say i have this array: `[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]`. If I use the method with `" "` it prints just fine. If i use `' '` though it prints this: `333534403736`.

Comment: In the first case you concatenate an index value with the literal string `" "`. In the second case you add up the index value to the numeric value of the character `' '` which is `32` and return the sum as a string. In short, `char` symbols have a numeric representation based on different coding tables (ASCII/UTF in this case) and you can do mathematical operations over them.

Comment: @zhulien ohh that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should also know that `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` invoke `.ToString()` implicitly on the passed argument, so you can skip "stringifying" the index by concatenating it to a string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quote represents a single character with the value `' '` (which is transformed to 32) where as a double quote appends a null terminator `'\0'` to the end of the string, so " " is actually `" \0"` and is larger in one byte than the intended size.

So for example, the iterations can be translated to:

```
1 + 32 // 33
3 + 32 // 35
2 + 32 // 34
8 + 32 // 40
5 + 32 // 37
4 + 32 // 36
```

Hence, the print will be: `333534403736`

Comment: The value of `'A'` is `65`, not `32`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int i in arr)
{
    Console.Write(i + ' ');
}
```

The above loop is taking `' '` 's int value which is 32 adding that with whatever value you have in `i` and showing it.